# SQL Server Query with boolean issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[TCCPAUsersAndNamesByJobPosition] @EmpOrfreeLance bit

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT distinct t1.UserId , tblCustomers.name 
    FROM tblTime t1
    inner join tblCustomers on t1.UserId=tblCustomers.custID
    where (t1.userid in (select distinct custID from tblCustomers where sectionCat Like '%,35%') )
    AND (t1.UserId in (select distinct custID from tblCustomers where IsEmployee = @EmpOrfreeLance))

end
```

tried it also with  `IsEmployee = CONVERT(bit,@EmpOrfreeLance)`

and `SET @EmpOrfreeLance= CASE @EmpOrfreeLance WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 0 END`

same all it retuns same list with same results no matter what

Shouldn't it be simple ???

`IsEmployee` col-datatype is `(bit,null)`

my dev SQL server is 2008 ..online server is 2005 should it be a matter ...

Comment: You can remove the `distinct` keyword for the select's inside in `IN` as it will do nothing.

Comment: @Magnus thanks , done , but i shall leave it as it is here  with your comment as an example to somthing that has not effect .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing null values will always return false.  You've stated that IsEmployee can be null which is probably your case.

```
1 == NULL => False
0 == NULL => False
NULL == NULL => False
```

Try using something like this for your comparison:

```
(@EmpOrfreeLance IS NULL
    OR IsEmployee IS NULL
    OR IsEmployee = @EmpOrfreeLance)
```

Or

```
ISNULL(IsEmployee, 0) = ISNULL(@EmpOrfreeLance, 0)
```

Comment: I should have noted that this is how SQL Server allows you to control this with the ANSI_Nulls option on your database and/or query.

Comment: what are those actually , i totally neglected them :`SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
`

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something, but why dont you write the query like this?

```
SELECT distinct t1.UserId, tblCustomers.name 
FROM tblTime t1
inner join tblCustomers on t1.UserId=tblCustomers.custID
where sectionCat Like '%,35%' AND 
      ISNULL(IsEmployee, CAST(0 As bit)) = @EmpOrfreeLance
```

Also you are going to have to decide what to do when `IsEmployee` is null. (is it an Employee or not) For example by using `ISNULL(IsEmployee, CAST(0 As bit))` to treat `NULL` values a `false`.

Answer (score 0):

i was wrong caus i missed a thing

```
    SELECT distinct t1.UserId , tblCustomers.name 
    FROM tblTime t1
    inner join tblCustomers on t1.UserId=tblCustomers.custID
    where (t1.userid in (select distinct custID from tblCustomers where sectionCat Like '%,35%') )
    AND (t1.UserId in (select distinct custID from tblCustomers where IsEmployee = @EmpOrfreeLance))
AND (isActive = 1 AND isActiveAgent  = 1 AND sivug Like '%,35%' AND custType = 1) 
or (isActive  = 1 AND isActiveAgent  = 1 AND sivug Like '%,35%' AND custType = 3) 
or (isActive  = 1 AND isActiveAgent  = 1 AND sivug Like '%,35%' AND custType  between  5 AND 12 )
```

i did not want to show all data and i did not notes that on other lines i emited there was an OR

so i had to add it to there too

Comment: You can optimize that where with: `...AND isActive = 1 AND isActiveAgent  = 1 AND sivug Like '%,35%' AND (custType = 1 OR custType = 3 OR custType between 5 AND 12)`